# Window.requestAnimationFrame() not workig in combination with stopImmediatePropagation

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to speed up webpage but since I am new to JavaScript, optimization doesn't go without errors. I created onclick transition effect that I would like to combine with Window.requestAnimationFrame(). When I add this line of code i get transition effect but an error pops up in console with a message:

*Uncaught TypeError: Window.requestAnimationFrame is not a function*.
This message is repeated in console in milliseconds. So I have thousand or so messages in few minutes. Like some kind of a loop.

Here is the code:

```
    function showNews(event) {
        requestAnimationFrame(showNews);
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        document.getElementsByClassName("News")[0].style.cssText = "width:45%; height: 100%; transition: 0.5s; overflow-y: auto";
        document.getElementsByClassName("Menu_item")[1].getElementsByTagName("A")[0].blur();
        document.getElementsByClassName("News")[0].focus();
    } 
document.getElementsByClassName("Menu_news")[0].addEventListener("click", showNews, false);
```

Comment: try `requestAnimationFrame(function(ts) { console.log('requestAnimationFrame called at: ' + ts);});` your other code will create an infinite loop since showNews is called again from `requestAnimationFrame`.

Comment: requestAnimationFrame is not receiving an event... read the documentation

Answer (score 0):

*Uncaught TypeError: Window.requestAnimationFrame is not a function* is happening when your brother does not support `requestAnimationFrame`.
But I would be surprised if it is the case.
The loop you are seing justly is the effect of `requestAnimationFrame(showNews)`.
What is happening is that the first time `showNews` is called, i.e. when you click on `.Menu_news`, it requests itself (`showNews`) to be called again at next animation frame.
Then when it is called again it does it again (so it will be called a third time, then a fourth time and so and so on).
So your browser looks like it supports `requestAnimationFrame`.
If it really doesn't, try to use a polyfill like [this one](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/1579671) but I really don't think you need it.

What is going to throw errors though is `event.stopImmediatePropagation();` because when `requestAnimationFrame` calls `showNews`, it does not give it an event but a number (a timestamp). This number obviously does not have a `stopImmediatePropagation` method. I believe this is the source of the error you are seing.

What you could do to fix it is to replace `event.stopImmediatePropagation();` with :

```
if(event && isNaN(event)){
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
}
```

It will solve this immediate issue.

**But it is probably not really what you are trying to achieve** (though I have no idea what it is).

Indeed creating an animation loop like you are doing here doesn't make sense.
There isn't any operation in `showNews` that are meant to animate something.
Worse, even if it was working the `blur` and `focus` function will just block user focus on `.News` node (because of the `requestAnimationFrame` you are creating).
The CSS you are creating does define a animated transition, but it will be automatically managed by the browser and it surely doesn't need to be manually set again at each animation frame. One time is enough.

Comment: Since I am just learning JavaScript I guess I just misunderstood  requestAnimationFrame. I thought this method helps on ANY animation or transition effect, hover effect etc.

Comment: No you do not need requestAnimationFrame for CSS animation. `requestAnimationFrame` is meant to be used to create performant JS driven animation. If you are interested, here is an article about it: https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2011/05/03/better-javascript-animations-with-requestanimationframe/